# How do I call a super constructor outside a constructor?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, constructor, ecmascript-6

Now that JavaScript has classes I'm wondering how it is possible to invoke a super constructor outside of a class constructor.

My unsuccessful naive attempt (results in a SyntaxError):

```
class A
{
    constructor() { this.a = 1; }
}

function initB()
{
    super(); // How to invoke new A() on this here?
    this.b = 2;
}

class B extends A
{
    constructor() { initB.call(this); }
}
```

I'm aware that in some other language like Java a super constructor can only be invoked inside the constructor of a derived class, but ES6 classes are syntactic sugar for prototype-based inheritance, so I'd be surprised if this were not feasible using built-in language features. I just can't seem to figure out the proper syntax.

The best I've come with so far feels terribly like cheating:

```
class A
{
    constructor() { this.a = 1; }
}

function initB()
{
    let newThis = new A();
    newThis.b = 2;
    return newThis;
}

class B extends A
{
    constructor() { return initB(); }
}
```

Comment: What's preventing you from using the standard `class B extends A { constructor() { super(); this.b = 2; }}`, as it is supposed to be?

Comment: Your "solution" is in fact a syntax error.

Comment: @Bergi I know my first approach is a syntax error, that's why I'm asking. I clarified my question, thanks.

Comment: Actually I meant the second one. Yes, your first snippet is a syntax error as well.

Comment: @Bergi the second one is working fine for me in Chrome 49. What line gives a SE in your browser?

Comment: The constructor doesn't contain a `super()` call. Babel gets this right, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>**Every** constructor of a class that `extends` something **must** contain a direct `super(…)` call.</s>
Direct `super(…)` calls can only be placed in constructors. There's really no way around this.

You really should not place the initialisation logic of a class anywhere else than in its constructor. The straightforward and proper solution is not to use `initB` at all:

```
class A {
    constructor() { this.a = 1; }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.b = 2;
    }
}
```

That said, there is a way to subvert the "`super()` call must be in the constructor" requirement. Putting it inside an arrow function counts as well! So you could do

```
class A {
    constructor() { this.a = 1; }
}

function initB(_super) {
    var b = _super();
    b.b = 2;
}
class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        initB(() => super());
    }
}
```

Promise me to not ever do that, please.

Another pattern is not to call `super()` at all, which works as long as you return an object from the constructor. With that, you can put the actual construction of the object anywhere else:

```
class A {
    constructor() { this.a = 1; }
}

function makeB() {
    var b = Reflect.construct(A, [], B); // call the A constructor with B for the prototype
    b.b = 2;
    return b;
}
class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        return makeB();
    }
}
```

Which really isn't much better.

Comment: "Putting it inside an arrow function counts as well!" --- is it as per the standard? `const a = () => { super() };` --- this fools babel as well, but having the ability to avoid invoking a parent constructor looks destructive :-S

Comment: To clarify, the `super` call is only needed if you want to use `this`.

Comment: @Oriol but how about [babel/repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=true&playground=true&code=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%20this.a%20%3D%201%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20a%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20super()%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.a%20%3D%20this.b%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)?

Comment: It's funny, but the babel generates broken JS from your second example.

Comment: Or maybe not. I remember reading somwehere the `super` call was not needed if you didn't use `this`. But Firefox and babel throw. Now I don't have time to look at the spec.

Comment: @Oriol I believe that it's only about placing some other code *before* `super()` call: you may put anything before `super()` as soon as it does not deal with instance members, but you still must invoke it somewhere in the constructor.

Comment: @Oriol: The `super` call is required by the [early errors for class constructors](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-class-definitions-static-semantics-early-errors). Using `this` only requires to actually have called it (so that accessing `this` doesn throw a runtime exception).

Comment: @zerkms: Yes, it is per the standard (there's even an [explicit note here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions-static-semantics-contains) advocating it). Yes, it certainly could be destructive, but so could be `constructor() { if (false) super(); return {}; }` :-)

Comment: @Bergi I think you're reading the negations in that early error backward, `super()` is forbidden if there is no `extends`, but as long as you return an explicit value in a class with `extends`, `super()` is not required.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: Oh bummer, you're right. And apparently [even Babel got fooled by this](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015&code=class%20A%20{}%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20{%0A%20%20constructor%28%29%20{%20}%0A}). Want to report a bug?