# ES6 use `super` out of class definition

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to add extra methods to class, and these extra methods should use the `super` methods.

If I add them in the model definition, it works.

```
class A {
    doSomething() {
        console.log('logSomething');
    }

}

class B extends A {
    doSomething() {
        super.doSomething();
        console.log('logSomethingElse');
    }
}
```

If I try to add the extra method to `B.prototype`, I'll get `SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here`.

```
class A {
    doSomething() {
        console.log('logSomething');
    }

}

class B extends A {
}

B.prototype.doSomething = function doSomething() {
    super.doSomething();
    console.log('logSomethingElse');
}
```

It is quite clear, why I get this error. This is a function and not a class method.

Let's try to define the method as a class method, and copy it to the original `B` class:

```
class A {
    doSomething() {
        console.log('logSomething');
    }

}

class B extends A {}

class X {
    doSomething() {
        super.doSomething();
        console.log('2 logSomethingElse');
    }
}

B.prototype.doSomething = X.prototype.doSomething;
```

In this case I'll get `TypeError: (intermediate value).doSomething is not a function`.

Is there any way to define methods (that refer to `super`) outside from the original class definition, and add these methods later to the original class?

Comment: Sorry, I hastily closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36273140/how-do-i-call-a-super-constructor-outside-a-constructor - but that is about calling `super()` rather than the method on the super class. Pretty sure the answer may be the same though

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`super` refers to ancestor of a class where the method was defined, it isn't dynamic. As [Babel output](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEAa0G8BQ1XQCYHsDKmC2ApgC4AWAlgHYDmAFAJSIprMQCuADgQE4B0WuhUpVp0A3E1QBfJNKA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&targets=&version=6.26.0) illustrates this, `super` is hard-coded to `Object.getPrototypeOf(X.prototype)`, and thus orphan class like this one doesn't make sense because it doesn't have `super`:

```
class X {
    doSomething() {
        super.doSomething();
        ...
    }
}
```

But `super` can be substituted with dynamic counterpart:

```
doSomething() {
    const dynamicSuper = Object.getPrototypeOf(this.constructor.prototype);
    // or
    // const dynamicSuper = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this));
    dynamicSuper.doSomething();
    ...
}

class B extends A {}
B.prototype.doSomething = doSomething;
```

In this case it will refer to ancestor class of class instance where `doSomething` was assigned as prototype method.

Comment: > dynamicSuper < You don't want to do that. It doesn't work right in all situations and you can get yourself into an infinite loop. Example https://repl.it/MrdK. The only safe way to get super is statically. `const staticSuper = Object.getPrototypeOf(X.prototype);`

Comment: @JeffM Even if I don't (I really don't), that's the answer to the question. Sure thing, a dev should know what he/she's doing when messing with prototype chains.

Answer (score 1):

While I think this could be assumed as *anti-pattern*, you shouldn't use `super` outside from a `class`.

You can achieve that using `Object Literals`.

Refer to [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf)

```js
const A = {
  sayHello() {
    console.log("I am A");
  },
  
  Factory() {
    return Object.create(this);
  }
}

const B = {
  sayHello() {
   super.sayHello();
  }
}

Object.setPrototypeOf(B, A);

const c = B.Factory();

c.sayHello();
```

Answer (score -2):

If you don't make class X inherit from class B or A, the only way to call the method is `A.prototype.doSomething()` or more generally `A.prototype.doSomething.call(this_substitute, ...args)`.

Comment: But where I define the `X`, there is no `A`, because I'd might want to add this method to multiple classes. When I define the `X.doSomething`, I don't know which class will be the `super` one.

Comment: For a function not tied to a particular class, don't define it as a method. Just do a regular function. And if you need the "this" value, make it the first argument.

Comment: I don't need the `this`. I need the `super`.

Comment: super is just a way to give access to the parent class. If you don't have a parent class, super is useless.